# Hibernate Criteria API: Unable to use sqlRestriction(..): ORA-00904: Invalid identifier

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Does anyone know why the followng `sqlRestriction` doesn't work. I'm using the native Oracle `trunc(..)` function to trim the time portion of a DATE.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Publication.class);

// Some other, non-SQL restrictions...

criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trunc(pubmedImportDate) >= ?", 
                                         todayMinus24Months, 
                                         org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.DATE));
```

**Error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "PUBMEDIMPORTDATE": invalid identifier**

The query is based on the domain class `Publication` which has this field,

```
public class Publication implements java.io.Serializable {
   //...
   private Date pubmedImportDate;
   //..
    public Date getPubmedImportDate() {
        return this.pubmedImportDate;
    }
    public void setPubmedImportDate(Date pubmedImportDate) {
        this.pubmedImportDate = pubmedImportDate;
    }
}
```

Do I need to prefix `pubmedImportDate` with some alias? I see that the `pubmedImportDate` never gets linked to Hibernate's alias `this_`.

I've tried both of these:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Publication.class);
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Publication.class, "p"); // with p.pubmedImportDate
```

But the query always comes out as this:

```
from
    PUBLICATIONS_T this_ 
...
trunc(p.pubmedImportDate) >= ?
```

How do I link it up to `this_`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: `{alias}.column_name` has to be used to link it up to `this_`:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("trunc({alias}.pubmed_import_date) >= ?", 
                                         todayMinus24Months, 
                                         org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.DATE));
```

Also note it has to be the real DB column name (`pubmed_import_date`) not the class property (`pubmedImportDate`).